# AS3: is it possibile to set the cursor x and y?

Tags: actionscript-3

is it possibile to set the position of the mouse cursor? This is what I would like to do: when the user presses the mouse button over a movieclip, the movieclip starts dragging and on enterframe the cursor is positioned in the middle of the movieclip (don't tell me about lockcenter because I can't use it this way since my movieclip registration point is set at its top left corner). Basically, I would like to be able to force the cursor to reach the center of the movieclip when the user clicks it. Is this possible?

Comment: Things like that would be a ruin for Adobe's Flash. Imagine you land on a website with evil Flash ads that wont let your mouse cursor move! In the end you can't create an ego shooter in Flash since you can't rotate your character infinitely in one direction (except there is a trick?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words you're looking for this functionality: [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You cannot control the cursor with Flash. You'll have to solve it otherwise - what about setting your movieclip's registration point to the center?!

Comment: At this point, I can't change the registration point (it would be error-prone, I should modify a lot of things), so this is not an option. The fact is that "dropTarget value depends not only on what movie clip might be under what you just dragged, it also takes the mouse position into account". In my case this means an unperfect behavior in a menu: when you drag a movieclip upon a menu item, sometimes Flash fails in checking which movieclip you are on because it considers the position of the mouse too! But I don't always drag my movieclip starting from the center...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have proof, but I think that you are not allowed to take control of the cursor like that.

An alternative would be to hide the actual mouse cursor, and add a custom cursor instead that you could positioned relative to the real cursor position, or in the center of your drag target if that would be easier.  The problem would be that you have no way of knowing the exact appearance of the user's cursor.

Comment: When the real cursor leaves the flash, the fake one would be stuck somewhere, without reaching the border of the stage. Best solution would be to stop wanting to take control of the courser, it would be annoying for the user anyway.

Comment: Not necessary is it? We can always detect when the real cursor moves off the border & hide the fake cursor.

Comment: I'm only trying to solve an ancient droptarget bug with a trick: http://noahlittle.wordpress.com/2007/11/20/_droptarget-depends-on-mouses-position-not-just-mc-underneath/ Since at this point I can't modify the project too much, I was looking for a quick and dirty solution

Comment: I think the only solution to that issue is to ensure that your drop target is bigger that the drag target at all times. You'll probably have to use an invisible shape rather than the actual target object and include code to handle the resulting drop not being accurate.

Comment: It's not a matter of size, I tested this before... It's a metter of mouse position (read my comment below).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. The mouse coordinates are read only.

However I would suggest any of these instead :

- Hide the mouse using `Mouse.hide();`.
- Make your own pointer in the location of the mouse.
- Control this pointer as per your wish.

or

- When the mouse button is pressed, move the movieclip itself, if
  possible.

Comment: Would this change my scenario? I think the "inner" position of the mouse would be always the same (am I wrong?)...

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on loxxy's response:

Instead of moving the mouse cursor to the center of the object with `lockCenter`, you can manually move the object to be centered about the mouse cursor when the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event is fired on the object (just before you call `startDrag` on the object)

Here's a simple example:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite{
        public function Main() {
            var drag_object:Sprite = new Sprite()
            drag_object.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, .5);
            drag_object.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            drag_object.graphics.endFill();

            drag_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
            drag_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

            drag_object.x = 200;
            drag_object.y = 300;
            addChild(drag_object);
        }

        private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var obj:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
            obj.x = e.stageX - (obj.width * .5);
            obj.y = e.stageY - (obj.height * .5);
            obj.startDrag();
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var obj:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
            obj.stopDrag();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Marcela, it was anything too buggy: I bloodily refactored the app and I totally removed droptarget (I used hitTestObject and it worked like a charm).   :-)